# How to overlap days into a single "day"

Tags: c#, mysql, timestamp

Okay, so.  I've got a database which has a column of timestamps.  The start of the "day" is 7am.  So, say for today, it would start at 0700 on 6/25/12, and end at 0700 on 6/26/12.  I'm needing to do calculations within that 24 hour time span.  Now, I'm thinking of doing a query that gets all information starting at 0700 + 24 hours, but I'm not 100% on how to phrase said query.  Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caveat - code done from the top of my head, without Visual Studio, and without proper error handling, but this should show you how to set the necessary parameter values correctly, using a parameterized query.  This may contain syntax errors, but again, it should show you enough to get you going.  I added comments to explain the relevant code.

```
private System.Data.DataTable ExecuteSql(DateTime BusinessDate)
{

    System.Data.DataTable ReturnValue = new System.Data.DataTable;
    string sql = "Select * From myTable WHERE TimestampColumn >= @StartDate AND TimestampColumn < @EndDate";
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDb.Command(connectionString, sql);

    // For start date, we can't assume the user has passed in a date with a 
    // midnight time, so first, use DateTime.Date to get JUST the date at midnight, 
    // then add 7 hours to get to the desired start time.
    // For example, if the calling code had passed in 1/1/2001 8:00 AM we would use
    // the .Date property to get it to 1/1/2001 12:00 AM
    // and then add 7 hours.

    cmd.Parameters.Add(@StartDate, BusinessDate.Date.AddHours(7));

    // The end date - same logic, but instead of adding 7 hours, add 31 
    // (24 hours + 7 hours = 31 hours)

    cmd.Parameters.Add(@EndDate, BusinessDate.Date.AddHours(31));  // 24 + 7
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter ad = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    ad.Fill(ReturnValue)    

    return ReturnValue;
}
```

Comment: downvoted because BETWEEN isn't correct for date ranges as it is inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE timestamp >= 'start' AND timestamp < 'end'
```

Note that the end is excluded because otherwise you would query it again as the start of the next day in a following query.

The `BETWEEN AND` operator includes the left and the right operators. If a timestamp is exacly at `0700` you have to decide whether is belongs to last period or the new period.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
your_needed_columns 
FROM 
your_table 
WHERE 
your_timestamp_column BETWEEN 'start_timestamp' AND 'end_timestamp'
```

This would be an example of using the BETWEEN statement which would server to accomplish what you are trying.

As per Ollie's comment, BETWEEN is inclusive, so my syntax is based upon the ending time intentionally being included in the results.  As others have stated, if you wish to include the beginning but exclude the ending then you must use `>=` and `<`

```
SELECT 
your_needed_columns 
FROM 
your_table 
WHERE 
your_timestamp_column >= 'start_timestamp' AND your_timestamp_column < 'end_timestamp'
```

Comment: downvoted because BETWEEN isn't correct for date ranges as it is inclusive.